# How to simulate an AR(1) model in R with rho equals to 1

Tags: r, arima

I want to simulate an AR(1) model x_t = rho * x_(t-1) + e_t, where rho=1, n=1050, so I tried the following code in R.

```
 y <- arima.sim(list(order = c(1,0,0), ar = 1), n = 1050)
```

But R returns the following message: Error: 'ar' part of model is not stationary.
How can I simulate this AR(a) model in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy way to do this is

```
y <- cumsum(rnorm(1050, 0, 1))
```

(assuming your e_t terms are normal with mean 0 and variance 1)

Answer (score 0):

Your `AR` coefficient of one is essentially just adding a differencing term, so your model is an `ARIMA(0,1,0)` model.  (Since this is non-stationary, `R` does not like you trying to put it into the `AR` part.)  The code to simulate from this model is:

```
y <- arima.sim(list(order = c(0,1,0)), n = 1050)
```